# Save Email after login with ldap

Tags: plugins

I am using simple ldap login plugin to login into wordpress from active directory. But after successful login the username field is ok but email field is empty in wordpress users table.

How can i make email saved in the database using this plugin.

The link to plugin is:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-ldap-login/

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: If this is a free plugin, then update your question with the link to the plugin.

Comment: plugin related questions are better asked at the plugin support channels. That being said, from my own understanding of how ldap is used the user may not have an email address at all.

Comment: @mark i did not got any reply from plugin owner, and the user has email address in AD.

Comment: the point of that general suggestion is that is unlikely that there is anyone here with expertise in every specific plugin. LDAP is even more esoteric then usual.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after i entered the Base DN in plugin settings to DC=domain,DC=suffix, previously it was empty.